# Force constructor parameter value in Json.net deserialization

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

Is it possible to force Json.net to pass a default value for a constructor parameter?

I have tried using a custom `ContractResolver` that overrides the `CreateConstructorParameters` and `CreatePropertyFromConstructorParameter` methods and sets the returned `JsonProperty.DefaultValue` property to my desired value and `DefaultValueHandling` property to `DefaultValueHandling.Populate`.

By overriding the `CreateObjectContract` method, I can see that the matching `CreatorParameters` and `Properties` both include my default value. However, I am still getting a `null` value passed to the constructors.

I have even tried setting the `Converter` on the properties to a converter that simply returns the desired default value, but still no luck.

Below is the ConstractResolver code:

```
public class DataControllerContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    ///The desired default value
    private readonly IDataController _dataController;

    private readonly Type _dataControllerType;
    private readonly JsonConverter<IDataController> _converter;

    public DataControllerContractResolver(IDataController dataController)
    {
        _dataController = dataController;
        _dataControllerType = dataController.GetType();
        _converter = SimpleJsonConverter<IDataController>.From((reader, controller, arg3) => _dataController, (writer, controller, arg3) => {});
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateConstructorParameters(ConstructorInfo constructor, JsonPropertyCollection memberProperties)
    {
        var props = base.CreateConstructorParameters(constructor, memberProperties);

        foreach (var prop in memberProperties.Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(_dataControllerType)).ToList())
        {
            prop.DefaultValue = _dataController;
            prop.Converter = _converter;
            prop.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate;
            prop.Ignored = false;
        }

        foreach (var prop in props.Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(_dataControllerType)).ToList())
        {
            prop.DefaultValue = _dataController;
            prop.Converter = _converter;
            prop.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate;
            prop.Ignored = false;
        }


        return props;
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreatePropertyFromConstructorParameter(JsonProperty matchingMemberProperty, ParameterInfo parameterInfo)
    {
        var prop = base.CreatePropertyFromConstructorParameter(matchingMemberProperty, parameterInfo);

        if (prop.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(_dataControllerType))
        {
            prop.DefaultValue = _dataController;
            prop.Converter = _converter;
            prop.MemberConverter = _converter;
            prop.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate;
            prop.Ignored = false;
        }

        return prop;
    }

    protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
        return contract;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After not finding a built-in solution to this issue, I buckled down and added the default value check and a [pull-request](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/pull/546) on Github. JamesNK (the Json.net creator) [implemented the solution](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/commit/7e04b45894b3c1d43387a2f83202a9c06910938c) slightly differently, but it is available in the latest builds.

Answer (score 1):

I can make this work if I override [`property.DefaultValue`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_DefaultValue.htm) and [`property.DefaultValueHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_DefaultValueHandling.htm) in [`CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_CreateProperties.htm).  I don't have all your classes (no `IDataController`), so here's a simple example:

```
public class DefaultStringValueContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public string DefaultStringValue { get; set; }

    public DefaultStringValueContractResolver(string defaultStringValue)
    {
        this.DefaultStringValue = defaultStringValue;
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        // Set all string properties to have a default value of "this is a default value"
        foreach (var property in properties.Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string)))
        {
            property.DefaultValue = DefaultStringValue;
            property.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate;
        }
        return properties;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
public class TestClass
{
    const string DefaultStringValue = "This is a default string value";

    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    public static void Test()
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new DefaultStringValueContractResolver(DefaultStringValue) };
        var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>("{}", settings);
        Debug.Assert(test.Property1 == DefaultStringValue && test.Property2 == DefaultStringValue); // No assert
        Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test)); // Prints {"Property1":"This is a default string value","Property2":"This is a default string value"}
    }
}
```

One thing to note: if the default value is a reference type, all instances of the class containing the property will have default values referring to the same default value instance.

Comment: Thank you for writing this answer. This definitely works to ensure that the properties are set to the default value. My issue is that this does not pass the default value to the constructor. Using your TestClass, if you add a constructor: `public TestClass(string property1, string property2){...}` the parameters are still null.

Comment: After walking through the source code, I found that oddly the method that populate the constructor params array only loops through the Json properties and compares them to the contract.CreatorParams - therefore only the serialized properties could be used for params. I created a pull request to add a second pass through the contract.CreatorParams that will set 'null' values to the provided DefaultValue.